# FQL get friends not authorized my app

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

How can I get friend list who have not authorized my application yet? I want to send invites to them.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I got the answer. Here is the query:

SELECT uid, name, pic_square FROM user 
   WHERE is_app_user=0 AND uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me())

Comment: I tried this querey in FQL at https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/145634995501895/?method=GET&path=me%3Ffields%3Did%2Cname&version=v2.1, but it doesn't work there.